# SSIS ForEach Loop Container Error: The GetEnumerator method of the ForEach Enumerator has failed with error 0x80131509 "(null)"

Tags: sql-server, permissions, ssis

I have done quite a bit of research on this and nothing has helped so far.
I have a multi-tab Excel file I need to load into a sql staging table.  I created a new project/package in SSIS to loop through the tabs and build into my table via a Foreach Loop Container.
When I run the package in SSIS, it works perfectly.  But when I run it through a sql job, it fails with this error.
If it matters, I run a script to rename the file to a standard name as it has a timestamp in the filename and I was having issues with wildcards.
My thought was a permissions issue but the file has Read for everyone.
We have just installed 34bit version of ado.net on our server (64bit version gave issues).

I apologize in advance if I'm not giving enough info, but not positive what all might be needed.

I greatly appreciate your time.
Chris

Comment: Hi Chris this is ringing a bell with me as I think I hit the same issue, I will hunt down my notes but in the mean time does this link help at all? 
Mentions the issue when using a local variable, if not let me know and I will continue to hunt through my folders of many things 

https://www.sqlservercentral.com/forums/topic/export-dtx-package-but-doesnt-work-on-sql-agent/page/2

Comment: That link is one of the ones I went over.  I added 'XM' in the ConnectionString of the ConnectionManager, but same error.

Comment: Thought it might be mate, will keep hunting through my notes

Comment: Does anyone know how to address this issue?
Thanks
Chris

Comment: Error 0x80131509 is `COR_E_INVALIDOPERATION` which is `An operation is not legal in the current state`.